# UINavigation controller back button title displays previous title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to set the back button title to just "Back". I've set the title "Back" in the storyboard (Navigation Item -> Back Button) and it appears to be working on iPhone X.

While testing on iPhone SE, I see the previous VC title as the back button title. So now it displays like "< APP NAME.......APP NAME......." which is a bit odd.

It'd have made sense if the iPhone X displayed it like above, because the screen width is longer, therefor it has more space for a longer title.

What could I do to make this work? I've already tried some things like:
Subclass UINavigation controller and add:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Do the above, but directly in the View Controllers.

Add spaces around the View Controller title to make it longer (doesn't work, and if it did than it's a bit hacky).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the backBarButtonItem property on the view controller that's currently displayed, or the one you want to go back to?

Comment: You could implement it as leftBarButtonItem

Comment: @RakeshaShastri _why_? Why would he do that when there's a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to set the `backBarButtonItem` is fine, but you're setting it on the wrong view controller.

If you have 2 view controllers VCA and VCB, and VCA pushes VCB onto it's navigation controller's nav stack, you need to set the `backBarButtonItem` in VCA, before pushing on VCB. You can do this in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
class VCA: UIViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that I should set this in VCA. I did, and it worked. Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

To modify the back button you should update it before pushing, on the view controller that initiated the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // This will show in the next view controller being pushed
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but what happens if the view controller isn't pushed using a segue?